# generating a column of times

Tags: r, dataframe, posixct

In my dataset, I want to include a column that contains only `times`. I have generated a column of random dates ranging from 2018 to 2020, but the time stamps don't appear to be generated as randomly throughout the day as I would like.

This is how I made the date/time column.

```
data$date <- sample(seq(as.POSIXct('2018/01/01'), as.POSIXct('2020/12/31'), by = "day"),
                    length(data$date), replace = TRUE)
```

and I am using it to get the times

```
data$time <- format(data$date, format = "%H:%M:%S")
```

but this is what it looks like

```
> dput(data[1:10,-c(5,6)])
structure(list(order_num = c(501073L, 969942L, 1091101L, 590143L, 
390404L, 219429L, 1025827L, 689629L, 694348L, 435848L), date = structure(c(1542344400, 
1552194000, 1550379600, 1534568400, 1523336400, 1563426000, 1595826000, 
1552712400, 1534309200, 1547960400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""), total_sale = c(36.3853391310075, 35.9405038506853, 
55.6254974332793, 47.7214780063544, 61.4086594373677, 32.8631076291332, 
33.3640439679803, 40.8944394660076, 54.9455495252506, 48.12597580998
), season = c("Spring", "Winter", "Winter", "Fall", "Fall", "Spring", 
"Summer", "Summer", "Fall", "Fall"), time = c("00:00:00", "00:00:00", 
"00:00:00", "01:00:00", "01:00:00", "01:00:00", "01:00:00", "01:00:00", 
"01:00:00", "00:00:00")), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am hoping for more random times throughout the day, such as 9:33:35, 14:56:43, and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can generate random times using -

```
data$time <- format(as.POSIXct(sample(86400, nrow(data)), origin = '1970-01-01'), '%T')
```

This generates random numbers from 1 to 86400 (seconds in a day) changes it to `POSIXct` type and extracts only the time from it using `format`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this function will help you generate random times throughout the day as you mentioned

```
randomtimes <- function(N, st="2018/01/01", et="2020/12/31") {
  st <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(st))
  et <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(et))
  dt <- as.numeric(difftime(et,st,unit="sec"))
  ev <- sort(runif(N, 0, dt))
  rt <- st + ev
}
```

Then you can just apply this to your data. Here `nrow` just counts the number of rows in your data and then uses that value to generate the number of dates. You could also just swap out `nrow(data)` with 10 since that is the number of rows in your data

```
data$date <- randomtimes(nrow(data))
```

Comment: this worked great, thank you!